# How to pass `component` into tab panel when active?

Tags: reactjs, components, antd

Please explain to me how to pass `component` into tab panel when active in `antd` library? Example component Productshoe

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
      <TabPane tab="productshoe" key="productshoe">
          <Productshoe/>
      </TabPane>
```

but it makes error

Comment: *it makes error* is not a problem description. What is the **full, complete error message** that you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `key` in TabPane doesn't match with the key of parent `Tabs`. Try to keep the key value same. And keep key values unique if you add more tabs.
Reference: [Link](https://ant.design/components/tabs/)

```
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="productshoe" onChange={callback}>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="productshoe">
      <Productshoe/>
    </TabPane>
  </Tabs>
```

Comment: i didn't  set default tabpane acitve key match with defaultActivekey so it show nothing..I fixed it. Thank you, bro !